# Hide index.php in subdirectory after rewrite (lighttpd)

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

**How it is set up now**

I have a website which is setup for clean urls with apache mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

The site also uses a CMS called Cockpit which lives under my public directory with a similar .htaccess file for it's clean urls:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In both cases `RewriteEngine On` is present also (of course).

Now on apache this results in the urls of my website being rewritten like this

```
http://domain.com/a
http://domain.bom/b
```

and the cockpit urls do practically the same:

```
http://domain.com/cockpit/a
http://domain.com/cockpit/b
```

**What I'm looking into**
So I've been looking into leaving apache behind for lighttpd and I've been messing around quite a bit with their mod_rewrite syntax and configuration but I have come across an issue where the cockpit urls aren't totally clean. This is how I have it set up on lighttpd:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "domain.com" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/domain.com/public_html"
        index-file.names = ( "index.php" )
        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(\/cockpit)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)*$" {
                url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^(.*)$" => "/cockpit/" )
        } else $HTTP["url"] !~ "^(\/cockpit)(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)*$" {
                url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^(.*)$" => "/index.php" )
        }
}
```

This config setup works but the cockpit urls are now these:

```
http://domain.com/cockpit/index.php/a
http://domain.com/cockpit/index.php/b
```

I'd like to get rid of the `index.php` part of the url like apache did but I'm haven't been able to get this to work properly.

**Anyone any ideas on this matter?**
s